# What is the best practice to follow if two people made changes in the same file and want to commit there code to git?

Tags: eclipse, git

I am working in a team on Selenium WebDriver in Java. For eg. If I and one of my team member are working on the same file. Every time someone commits some changes into the repository and when I pull the code, eclipse shows conflicts even if a new line of code has been added to the file. Is there any way to merge both the codes without this conflict?

Comment: People should learn to update code before they commit.

Comment: it is very difficult to tell without a lot more information, (like a minimal sample source file of only 3 lines, an exact sequence of steps to reproduce the problem, screenshots from eclipse, etc.) but what is probably happening is that you are committing the file with different line endings.  (a.k.a. end-of-lines, eolns for short.)  So, read about line endings in eclipse and in git, and make sure that your line endings are handled properly.

Comment: Try not to be editing the same file.

Comment: Do a `git pull --rebase` and resolve conflicts locally before the `git push`. Keep commits small, and stop people from working on the same artifact simultaneously. This is not a Java question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to do it that way :

```
git add [your file]
git commit "fix"
git pull origin master
git push origin master
```

The conflicts may occur because you don't commit your changes before pulling from the repository.